# How to plot a deadband for a simple sine wave using python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am using the below codes so as to plot the dead band for a sine wave so that the dead band appears on the x axis as y=0. The output is minimized by the value of upper limit[y-0.5] and the lower limit.The dead band needs to be displayed here.Could any one help me in this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

UpperLimit = 0.5;
LowerLimit = -0.5;

x=np.linspace(-20,20,100);
y=np.sin(x);

if y < 0:
   y=np.sin(x)-LowerLimit
if y > 0:
   y=np.sin(x)-UpperLimit
else:
   y=0

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should work with vectorized values, so try this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

LL = -0.5
UL = 0.5

x=np.linspace(-20,20,100)
y=np.sin(x)

# plot original sine
plt.plot(x,y)


# zero output value for the dead zone
y[(y>=LL) & (y<=UL)] = 0

y[y>UL] -= UL
y[y<LL] -= LL

# plot "simulinked" ....
plt.plot(x,y)

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

PS it would much easier to understand what you want if you would provide a link to the ["Dead Zone" algorithm](http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/deadzone.html), because not all of us aware of it

Comment: do you have an algorithm, describing how should it be calculated?

Comment: The output must be zero for certain x values in addition being symmetric about the x axis.The output is similar to that of the dead zone block used in Simulink.

Comment: :Please consider the upper limit and the lower limit as the thresholds.The y value needs to exceed the threshold value so that the output value appears .When the y value is below the threshold ,the output appears as zero on x axis.The x values have no control over the dead band of the output value.The dead band is controlled by the value of upper limit and the lower limit.

Comment: Ausgezeichnet.This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having an `if` statement acting on your array, you need to iterate through your array of `y` values and [modify each one](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#modifying-array-values). Also, with an `if` statement of `y > 0` or `y < 0` will not achieve the deadband result you are looking for. Instead, you should use `y > UpperLimit` or `y < LowerLimit`

This should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

UpperLimit = 0.5;
LowerLimit = -0.5;

x=np.linspace(-20,20,100);
y=np.sin(x);

for y_point in np.nditer(y, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    if y_point > UpperLimit:
        y_point[...] -= UpperLimit
    elif y_point < LowerLimit:
        y_point[...] -= LowerLimit
    else:
        y_point[...] = 0

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: please do not iterate through numpy arrays, pandas data frames/series, other vectorized data unless it's __absolutely necessary__  ...

Comment: OK. Thank you for the tip. I didn't realize it can be done the way you did it. What is it called when you aren't iterating over the array? When you do this: `y[y>something] = stuff`